# Error: Cannot find module './path/path/file' with docker running a Node container

Tags: node.js, docker

The node project I am trying to containerize is depending on another project I have called config.

```
systemConfig = require("./common/config/config"); <-------------THIS
systemConfig.init("partnerService");
const config = systemConfig.get();
```

The docker files looks like this :

```
FROM node:12

ENV PORT=8080\
CONFIG_FOLDER=/Users/romansterlin/Desktop/nodejs-services \
CONFIG_NAME=configuration.json

WORKDIR /alerts

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]

RUN npm install

COPY .  .

EXPOSE 1400

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

After creating the container and trying to run it I am getting an error :

> Error: Cannot find module './common/config/config'

is there a way to include that project inside the container?

the folders structure:

```
NODEJS-SERVICES/
├── alerts-service
│   └── index.js
└── common
    └── shared_module
```

Comment: Change the CMD to a Sleep command (CMS ["sleep", 300d"]) and go in the container after it started. Your working directory is /alerts.  Is there a /alerts/common/config/config in the Container?

Comment: doesn't seems like it if im looking at the right place.
I opened the container in docker desktop and checked there for the directory but it seems like the wrong place..
I also. tried "docker exec -it container , ls got me the contents of the docker and all I see is files from the node project, nothing related to common/config
NODEJS-SERVICES is the base directory of common and alerts-service if that helps.

Comment: I added the directory structure to post maybe it can help

Comment: alright i figured out what u meant and I managed to fix the problem, ill update an detailed solution tomorrow. appreciate the help!